# How to calculate group of sequent nonzero rows in R using 1 row above and 1 row after that group?

Tags: r

I want to create another data frame (df) that lists only events. For example, there should be 4 events in df(XX,YY). The column XX should be sum of event value greater than zero separated by zero rows. The column YY should be Max minus Min of event value greater than zero separated by zero rows.

```
    XX   YY
1  3.0 23.6
2  0.0 23.2
3  0.0 23.7
4  0.0 25.2
5  1.3 24.5
6  4.8 24.2
7  0.2 23.1
8  0.0 23.3
9  0.0 23.9
10 0.0 24.3
11 1.8 24.6
12 3.2 23.7
13 0.0 23.2
14 0.0 23.6
15 0.0 24.1
16 0.2 24.5
17 4.8 24.1
18 3.7 22.1
19 0.0 23.4
20 0.0 23.8
```

From my table, I would like to get the results as following.

Event 1. XX[1] = sum(row1,row2) ; YY[1] = [Max(row1,row2)- Min(row1,row2)] 
XX[1]=3, YY[1]=0.4

Event 2. XX[2] = sum(row4,row5,row6,row7,row8) ; YY[2] = [Max(row4,row5,row6,row7,row8)- Min(row4,row5,row6,row7,row8)] 
XX[2]=6.3, YY[2]=2.1

Event 3. XX[3] = sum(row10,row11,row12,row13) ; YY[3] = [Max(row10,row11,row12,row13)- Min(row10,row11,row12,row13)] 
XX[3]=5, YY[3]=1.4

Event 4. XX[4] = sum(row15,row16,row17,row18,row19) ; YY[4] = [Max(row15,row16,row17,row18,row19)- Min(row15,row16,row17,row18,row19)] 
XX[4]=5, YY[4]=2.4

```
   XX    YY
1  3    0.4
2  6.3  2.1
3  5    1.4
4  8.7  2.4
```

Comment: So what's the problem with just calculating those 4x2 entries like you describe? TBH, I don't understand the logic behind calculating these numbers. For example, for `XX` you sum across different numbers of rows; why those rows? And why are some rows ignored (e.g. row3, row9, etc.)? Perhaps you should rethink if there is a better way of storing your original data; perhaps a `list` of `data.frame`s? Then you can apply a function (summing and "max-min"'ing) to every `data.frame` in the `list`.

Comment: @Maurits Evers, it happened that the given data frame is from a recording device. YY is temperature, and XX is time it needs to cool down item. I need to find f(x) =  [max(temperature)-min(temperature)]/sum(time), per event. A device would turn on and cool down item, and then turn off. It will work in this cycle repeatedly. I cannot modify the original data.

Comment: I see. I've edited my answer, please take a look. It boils down re-formatting the original data into a `list` of `data.frame`s first, and then applying a simple function to every element of the `list`.

Answer (score 2):

### Method 1 in base R

1. Split the original `data.frame` into a `list`.

   ```
   lst <- split(df, c(rep(1, 2), 2, rep(3, 5), 4, rep(5, 4), 6, rep(7, 5), 8));
   lst <- lst[sapply(lst, function(x) nrow(x) > 1)];
   names(lst) <- NULL;
   ```

   Note that this is exactly the same as your original data, with the only difference that relevant rows are grouped into separate `data.frame`s, and irrelevant rows (row3, row9, row14, row20) have been removed.
2. Next define a custom function

   ```
   # Define a custom function that returns
   # the sum(column XX) and max(column YY)-min(column YY)
   calc_summary_stats <- function(df) {
       c(sum(df$XX), max(df$YY) - min(df$YY));
   }
   ```
3. Apply the function to your `list` elements using `sapply` to get your expected outcome.

   ```
   # Apply the function to the list of dataframes
   m <- t(sapply(lst, calc_summary_stats))
   colnames(m) <- c("XX", "YY");
   #      XX  YY
   #[1,] 3.0 0.4
   #[2,] 6.3 2.1
   #[3,] 5.0 1.4
   #[4,] 8.7 2.4
   ```

---

### Method 2 using `tidyverse`

Using `dplyr`, we can first add an `idx` column by which we group the data; then `filter` the groups with >1 row, calculate the two summary statistics for every group, and output the `ungroup`ed data with the `idx` column removed.

```
library(tidyverse);
df %>%
    mutate(idx = c(rep(1, 2), 2, rep(3, 5), 4, rep(5, 4), 6, rep(7, 5), 8)) %>%
    group_by(idx) %>%
    filter(n() > 1) %>%
    summarise(XX = sum(XX), YY = max(YY) - min(YY)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-idx);
## A tibble: 4 x 2
#     XX    YY
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1  3.00 0.400
#2  6.30 2.10
#3  5.00 1.40
#4  8.70 2.40
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "XX   YY
1  3.0 23.6
2  0.0 23.2
3  0.0 23.7
4  0.0 25.2
5  1.3 24.5
6  4.8 24.2
7  0.2 23.1
8  0.0 23.3
9  0.0 23.9
10 0.0 24.3
11 1.8 24.6
12 3.2 23.7
13 0.0 23.2
14 0.0 23.6
15 0.0 24.1
16 0.2 24.5
17 4.8 24.1
18 3.7 22.1
19 0.0 23.4
20 0.0 23.8", header = T)
```